# Using htaccess to rewrite special characters for Wordpress url aliases

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, drupal, redirect, special-characters

I recently migrated a fairly large site (~6,000 posts) from Drupal to Wordpress. As part of the process, I migrated the Drupal-created url aliases to Wordpress for SEO and link retention purposes.

An example of a url alias that Drupal created that worked great in Drupal:

- /stories/will-this-be-another-la-niña-year

That url in Wordpress returns a 404. However, this works:

- /stories/will-this-be-another-la-nina-year

It seems then my best bet is to write a generic international character to english character set rewrite rule in htaccess, before the url is passed to Wordpress.

Any idea how I might do this?
Thanks a lot for whatever help you can give.
Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there might be a better way to do this within wordpress, you may want to do a quick browser through the [wordpress Trac tickets](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/report), there maybe some patch or temporary fix for the problem. But if you need to go to an htaccess/redirect method, you can either use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to sanitize and redirect-if-needed or explicitly redirect on non-ascii characters.

A RewriteMap requires access to either server or vhost config to setup the map. It could be as simple as a list of `/stories/will-this-be-another-la-niña-year` URIs mapped to `http://yourdomain.com/stories/will-this-be-another-la-nina-year` (the all ascii URL, the `http://` is significant because it tells mod_rewrite to redirect the browser). Or you can write a script to look for non-ascii characters and replace them with the appropriate ascii character.

Text mapping:

```
RewriteMap sanitize txt:/path/to/uri_mapping.txt
```

Script mapping:

```
RewriteMap sanitize prg:/path/to/sanitize_script.php
```

Then in your htaccess file, you can invoke this mapping like this (these rules will need to be *above* the wordpress rules, since you want the URI sanitized *before* wordpress gets a hold of them.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${sanitize:$1|$1} [L]
```

If you don't have access to server/vhost config, you'll have to enumerate the possibilities in your htaccess file, again putting these rules above the wordpress rules:

```
# replace ñ
RewriteRule ^(.*)ñ(.*)$ /$1n$2 [R=301,L]

# replace ú
RewriteRule ^(.*)ú(.*)$ /$1ú$2 [R=301,L]
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, @Jon. Your ideas work for everything but the actual special chars. For instance, if I change the `# replace ñ` rewrite rule to replace "a" instead of "ñ", it rewrites the url with "n"s in place of "a"s. However, using `(.*)ñ(.*)$` doesn't do anything to rewrite the "ñ" in the URL. The RewriteMap method is acting the same way. Do you think this could be a server config issue, with how it's handling international characters? Thanks again.

Comment: @MattHarvey  There could be escaping going on. Try instead of `ñ`, replace it with the URL escaped `%C3%B1`.

Comment: It seems to be ignoring that, too. `RewriteRule ^(.*)%C3%B1(.*)$ /$1n$2 [R=301,L]` is what I'm using. Any other options? Thanks again.

Comment: @MattHarvey Not sure what to say, the rule works for me in an htaccess file in a local brand new apache install. There may be a unicode issue with whatever you're editing your htaccess file in, but it's probably something else.

Comment: I think it's a unicode issue with my host. They're making some changes from their end. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: For future potential explorers of this post: @JonLin's answer works perfectly. I just had an encoding issue with saving my htaccess file that was butchering the special characters in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following lines at the beginning of my .htaccess file and it works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)é(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)è(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ê(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)î(.*)$ /$1i$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ô(.*)$ /$1o$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)û(.*)$ /$1u$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)â(.*)$ /$1a$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)à(.*)$ /$1a$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ï(.*)$ /$1i$2 [R=301,L]
```